# Find $\cos(A-B)$ using given information

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan A = \dfrac25$ if angle $A$ is in quadrant I and $\cos B = -\dfrac23$ if angle $B$ is in quadrant $3$.

### Progress so far:

$$\cos(A-B) = \cos A\cos B + \sin A\sin B$$

If $\tan A$ is greater than $04, then the possible quadrants are I and III

$\tan A = \dfrac25$

$\tan = \dfrac{ \sin A}{\cos A}$

sinA = 2

cos A = 5

cos B = -2/3

So, on a triangle within the uni circle, x=-2, and r=3. To find y use pythagorean's theorem.

3^2-(-2)^2 = y^2

9-4 = y^2

y = sqrt5

Here is where I got slightly stuck. **What do I do in order to find the values of A and B?**

### EDIT 1:

sin A = 2/sqrt29

cos A = 5/sqrt29

[image]

Sorry for the picture, but I'm still quite inexperienced in terms of formatting. **Did I determine sin B and cos B correctly?**

### EDIT 2:

If sin A = -sqrt5/3, how can sin^2B = 5/9? Isn't the square root of 5/9 sqrt5/3, which is equal to sin A?

Here's what I have now:

[image]

### EDIT 3:

[image]

If I did everything right, this is the last edit! Is this correct?

### EDIT 4:

It should be (-10 **minus** 2sqrt5)/(3sqrt29), shouldn't it?

Comment: Note: $\sin A$ cannot equal $2$ and $\cos A$ cannot equal $5$ for any real $A$.

Comment: @David, do you mind expanding on that? How should I use the information I've been given to solve this then? Should I be using a trig identity here?

Comment: Draw a right triangle with legs $2$ and $5$, with the side opposite to angle $A$ equal to $2$. Then the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{29}$. Since $A$ is in the first quadrant, we have $\cos A=\frac{5}{\sqrt{29}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note:$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad-1\le\sin x\le1 \quad\text {and}  \quad-1\le\cos x\le1$

$$\tan A=\dfrac25\implies\cos A=\frac{5}{\sqrt{29}} \text{ and } \sin A=\frac{2}{\sqrt{29}}$$

> Answer to update

we  have $\cos{B}=-\dfrac{2}{3}$ Now use $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$

we get $\sin^2B=\dfrac59$ using the fact that $B$ isin $3^{rd}$ quadrant we get $\sin B=-\dfrac{\sqrt5}{3}$

I hope you can take it from here!

Comment: If sin^2 B = 5/9, what is sin B? sqrt5/3?

Comment: @MM98 There was a typo, Edited!

Comment: Noted, I guessed as much :)

Comment: Absolutely- making progress! Watch for edit in just a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right-angled triangle with angle $A$, opposite side $2$ and adjacent side $5$, so that $\tan A=\frac25$.  You should be able to read off the triangle that
$\sin A=\frac2{\sqrt{29}}$ and $\cos A=\frac5{\sqrt{29}}$.

If $B$ is in the third quadrant then $B-\pi$ is in the first quadrant and $\cos(B-\pi)=-\cos B=\frac23$.  Draw another triangle in order to find $\sin(B-\pi)$.

Then you should be able to find $\sin B$, $\cos B$ and then solve the problem.  Good luck!

Comment: That is a huge help. I found sin B and cos B (see edit– is that correct?)

Comment: Looks good to me.